# SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'xxx' at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, thinkphp

I am using thinkCMF Chinees PHP framework for the backend and Vue for the front end.

I wanted to make an image upload optional and I removed it from the server required (Controller).

but submitting the form it was giving the above error.

I changed the column varchar(200) to varchar(500) but didn't work.

Comment: if it is not a required field, Then you need to check, what data come in it after submit, Or make data type text in place of varchar to handle long data string.

Answer (score 1):

We check the value of image upload in the front end.
we make it optional from the front end then the issue is solved.

I was looking for a solution for a backend project but the solution was in a front-end project.

so the front team solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try use text to replace varchar(200)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).